# Office.context.mailbox.item return null

Tags: outlook-addin, office-js

I'm using office.js api to get the email and attachments in an outlook add-in and I ran into an issue where the office.js api returns null reference for some emails.

Any idea why this is happening ?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1.1/hosted/office.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

Office.initialize = function () {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var mailbox = Office.context.mailbox
        _Item = mailbox.item;
    })
}

</script>
```

[image]

Comment: Can you share your sample code. It would be helpful to understand more about the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This can happen if you don't check the page load status as described in this article: https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/develop/loading-the-dom-and-runtime-environment. Could you try using $(document).ready() function to see if that solves the problem?

Comment: I did use the code in the article but got same results.

Comment: Let's try to narrow this down. Is it consistently null for some emails, but not the others? How are those emails different from the ones it works well for? Which folder are they in - inbox? Which browser are you using? Do you have another client to try it on (win32 and mac desktop outlook) - if you do, do you see the same results? Is it possible for you to share your manifest so we could try to reproduce as well?

Comment: You can create such email like this:
Open outlook and click on "New Items" button and then select "Task".
In the new window, click on "Assign Task" and then send the task to any email you want.
When you open the email that was sent in outlook, all addin commands are disabled but in web they are all available.

Comment: Thank you for your response. We were able to reproduce this issue. Outlook does not support Add-in commands for task items, and the commands should not have been available in web. We apologize for any frustration or inconvenience we have caused with this issue. Please be patient as we work to fix this issue as quickly as we can.